# 32 bit Grayscale Image with CGBitmapContextCreate always Black

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm using the following code to display a 32 bit Grayscale image. Even if I explicitly set every pixel to be 4294967297 (which ought to be white), the end result is always black. What am I doing wrong here? The image is just 64x64 pixels.

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
ptr = (float*)malloc(4*xDim*yDim);
for(i=0;i<yDim;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<xDim;j++)
    {
        ptr[i*xDim + j] = 4294967297;
    }
}
CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                   ptr,
                                                   xDim,
                                                   yDim,
                                                   32,
                                                   4*xDim,
                                                   colorSpace,
                                                   kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapFloatComponents);

//ptr = CGBitmapContextGetData(bitmapContext);


//NSLog(@"%ld",sizeof(float));

CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);

NSRect drawRect;
drawRect.origin = NSMakePoint(1.0, 1.0);
drawRect.size.width = 64;
drawRect.size.height = 64;
NSImage *greyscale = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage size:NSZeroSize];
[greyscale drawInRect:drawRect
             fromRect:NSZeroRect
            operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
             fraction:1.0];
```

Comment: Have you seen somewhere that 32bit float greyscale is supported? I'm not saying its not.. just interested

Comment: Yes - you can see the supported pixel formats [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-SW9). You'll need to scroll a bit down.

Comment: Yes, looks like you are right

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the endianness, Quartz will default to big-endian. If you are on an Intel Mac, this will be wrong. You will need to explicitly set the endianness, and the best way to do that is to change your flags to:

```
kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapFloatComponents | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Host
```

This will work properly regardless of your CPU (for future compatibility!).
You can find more detail here: http://lists.apple.com/archives/Quartz-dev/2011/Dec/msg00001.html

Comment: Also, the values in your data array should be scaled to the range [0,1].

Answer (score 0):

You are using a float component image. Make sure ptr has type float* and try setting values to 0.5f instead of 4294967297.

Answer (score 0):

Are you showing the exact code you are using ?

2^32 - 1 = 4294967295

If you are using 4294967297 I suspect you are getting overflow and an actual value of 2 !

Answer (score 0):

32 bit floating point gray scale is not supported by CGBitmapContextCreate. [CGBitmapContextCreate Supported Color Spaces](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1037/_index.html)